# find files and act on them (find + exec)

Tags: unix, recursion, path, find, exec

I have downloaded about 3200 websites to the depth 2. So now I have one master folder (abc) that contains many folders, containing files for each website. So my folder abc contains 3200 folders and each folder contains other folders that contains files with text from the websites. 
I have also a script that can edit text in each file. It is stored in file named lynx.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
fileA=$1
while IFS= read -r lineA
do
LTRA=$(echo "${lineA:0:1}")
catA=$(lynx -dump -nonumbers -nomargins -nolist -noprint -width 1000 -assume_charset=utf-8 $2/*.* )
editA=$(echo "$catA" | sed -e 's/\[[^][]*\]//g')
editB=$(echo "$editA" | sed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g')
editC=$(echo "$editB" | sed '/^http/ d' )
editD=$(echo "$editC" | sed '/^IFRAME/ d' )
editE=$(echo "$editD" | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' )
editF=$(echo "$editE" | sed -r 's/[^aáäbcčdďdzdžeéfghchiíjklĺľmnňoópqrŕsštťuúvwxyýzžAÁÄBCČDĎDZDŽEÉFGHCHIÍJKLĹĽMNŇOÓPQRŔSŠTŤUÚVWXYÝZŽ][^aáäbcčdďdzdžeéfghchiíjklĺľmnňoópqrŕsštťuúvwxyýzžAÁÄBCČDĎDZDŽEÉFGHCHIÍJKLĹĽMNŇOÓPQRŔSŠTŤUÚVWXYÝZŽ]+//g' )
editG=$(echo "$editF" | sed s'/[^aáäbcčdďdzdžeéfghchiíjklĺľmnňoópqrŕsštťuúvwxyýzžAÁÄBCČDĎDZDŽEÉFGHCHIÍJKLĹĽMNŇOÓPQRŔSŠTŤUÚVWXYÝZŽ]$//')
editH=$(echo "$editG" | sed s'/^[^aáäbcčdďdzdžeéfghchiíjklĺľmnňoópqrŕsštťuúvwxyýzžAÁÄBCČDĎDZDŽEÉFGHCHIÍJKLĹĽMNŇOÓPQRŔSŠTŤUÚVWXYÝZŽ]//')
editI=$(echo "$editH" | sed 's/ .*//')
editJ=$(echo "$editI" | sed '/^$/d' )
echo "$editJ" > $2/"blaaa"_lynx.txt
echo "$lineA"
done <"$fileA"
```

It makes text in each file to be edited - every word is on the new line. I have used this script many times before but I use it with file input.txt which contains names of all websites that i have.

Now I am trying to edit all folders in my abc folder at once. I have tried to use somtehing like this:

```
find /home/student/eny/abc -exec lynx.sh {} \;
find /home/student/eny/abc/* -iname -exec ./lynx.sh input.txt {} \;
```

and many others. I can not find a solution for this.

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: No but it affect only first layer. I need to edit all folders and all files and all it does is that it affect only first folder but not its folders (eg. folder "abc" contains many folders that contain other folders but also contain some files. And all it does is that it affect only files in abc and not also folders) @JohnKugelman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for "**-type f**"

`find /home/student/eny/abc -type f -exec ./lynx.sh {} \;`